# Simultaneous development environment for SP2010 and SP2013 in single OS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010, virtual-machine, sharepoint-2013

I have on my laptop a development environment as win7 with std IIS, SharePoint 2010 Server, SQL 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010. I already installed Visual Studio 2012 side by side. But what about SharePoint 2013? I would like to develop and test for SP2010 as well as SP2013, but I don’t want to use any VM’s (this is only using more memory and more CPU cycles for again another full blown OS. I even don’t like VM’s any way on a laptop regarding sleep/hibernate and startup issues). Is there a way to accomplish this all in a “normal” fashion way? Or… what is the best way to achieve this? Can you install SP2010 and SP2013 side by side and how to setup the debugger for this (sometimes SP2010 and sometimes 2013) Or do you really need to install something like VM with SP2013 in it… and then do some remote deployment to this VM with the debugger attached to it? Is this even possible? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

I did post it on following URL: [SharePoint.StackExchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/simultaneous-development-environment-for-sp2010-and-sp2013-in-single-os)

You can read the answer there.